# Problems understanding the hexdump of static library(.a) in Linux

Tags: static-libraries, elf, hexdump

I've compiled a very simple C file with two functions in it to .a file in Linux, and I would like to get the functions offset from the bytes similar to the "nm" command, but I wanna write this program myself. I've hexdumped it expecting to find the "magic number" elf at the beginning, but it turns out that it is "!< arch>". I couldn't find if there is a structure to interpret the bytes at "!< arch>". How can I procede?

Answer (score 1):

The format of `ar` archives is [well documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)).

> expecting to find the "magic number" elf at the beginning

You'll find the `ELF` magic bytes at offset 60, i.e. after the first AR file header. However, you may have to skip special members, such as "archive index" (built by `ranlib`) if you have one.

Comment: So, I've found the ELF magic bytes, but it was almost at offse 144. Is that normal?

Comment: I've open the lib in a text editor, and before the ELF, there are the name of the two functions and the obj file name, respectively.

Comment: @MarcoVinicio I've updated the answer 4m ago. Does the update answer your question?

Comment: @MarcoVinicio It does *not* say that. You must read the specification carefully.